# Take slider value from jQuery ui slider and store it into a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, user-interface, slider

I am trying to take the values from this slider:

```
  $(function () {
     $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 2000,
        max: 8500,
        values: [2000, 8000],
        step: 200,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#dl-sv-input-mmr").val(ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);

        }
     });
      $("#dl-sv-input-mmr").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
        " - " + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
   });
```

How can I take it's current value and store it into a variable? I am trying to do a filter in AJAX that will get all elements in a certain range. I am a newb and not sure if this is the correct way to do it.

HTML:

```
  <label for="dl-sv-input-mmr" class="control-label col-xs-2">MMR:</label>

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dl-sv-input-mmr" name="dl-sv-input-mmr" readonly
                   style="border:0; color:black; font-weight:bold;">

            <div id="slider-range"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What you're doing is correct. Are there any issues?

Answer (score 0):

Please take note that you need to have this in your html in order for the code to work

```
<div id="slider-range"></div>
<input id="dl-sv-input-mmr" type="text"/>
```

Define this two global variables

```
var min = 0; 
var max = 0; 

$(function () {
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 2000,
        max: 8500,
        values: [2000, 8000],
        step: 200,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
              $("#dl-sv-input-mmr").val(ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
              min = ui.values[0]; //current min slider value
              console.log("min "+min);
              //You can also do min = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0);
              max = ui.values[1]; //current max slider value 
              console.log("max "+max);
              //You can also do max = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1);
        }
     });
    $("#dl-sv-input-mmr").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
                          " - " + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
    min = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0);
    max = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1);
});
```

Also note that you have to close `$(function() {`

Assigning `max` and `min` values inside your slide handler will ensure that everytime you will have the updated values.

At any point you can do 
    var min = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0);
    var max = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1);

Check 
http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-values

Check also if you are loading jQuery js file and jQuery-ui js and css

Comment: I tried this and when I log it to the console it logs only the 0. I tried it both ways.
EDIT: Console.log prints the correct values if it's inside the slider function. Any ideas?

Comment: Console logging the $("#dl-sv-input-mmr") returns blank space(nothing). I editted my original post and added the html. It looks like yours

Comment: are you closing $(function() {  ? You should have }); at the end

Comment: Yeah it's closed. Sorry I didn't copy the brackets from my IDE. My bad

Comment: edited once more you can also try console logging $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) and see if it's 0 or hopefully not :)

Comment: Yeah as I said in my first post it logs the correct values if the console.log is inside the function, but outside the values are 0. May be it just takes the initial values that I set them and logs them before the function sets them to 2000 and 8000. I will try to use this and see if it works with ajax. Thanks for the help!